# I can't seem to get my stored procedure to return the correct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, authentication

**SQL:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UserLogin (@username varchar(30), @password varchar(20))  
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [User] 
    WHERE User_ID = @username AND Password = @password

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
       RETURN 1
    ELSE
       RETURN 0
```

**VB:**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=SIMON;Initial Catalog=AlphaSYS39414;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx"

    Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim account As String = txtusername.Text
            Dim mypassword As String = txtpassword.Text
            Dim ResponseNum As Integer
            connection.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UserLogin", connection)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@username", account))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@password", mypassword))
            ResponseNum = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Debug.Print(ResponseNum)
            If ResponseNum = 1 Then
                Response.Redirect("https://google.com")
            Else
                Response.Redirect("https://yahoo.com")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to get my code stored procedure value to return a 1 or 0 and then redirect accordingly, but every time it seems to return a -1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your first SELECT gets in the way.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UserLogin (@username varchar(30), @password varchar(20))  
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE User_ID = @username AND Password = @password)
       RETURN 1
    ELSE
       RETURN 0
```

Do you really keep passwords in an SQL Server table? Not the safest thing to do.

Comment: Please accept / upvote if you find this answer useful, so the other can benefit from it.